# Improve/fix prime factorization function

Tags: c, function, factorization

I have a function prime factorization, but it works wierdly and I have no idea how to make it right.
It's expected to print factors through 'x' and write like 2^(power) or 3^(power) if 2's or 3's are reapeating factors.

MyOutput: 2 >> 22^2 | 6 >> 2 x 3^2 | 8 >> 22^22^3 | 9 >> 3 x 3^2.
How do I change this code to make it work properly.

Note: I have stated in main() that if num == 1: print 1.

```
void prime_factors(int num)
{
    int power = 0;

    for (int factor = 2; num > 1; ++factor)
    {
        while (num % factor == 0)
        {
            if (factor >= 3 && power >= 1)
                printf(" x %d", factor);
            else
                printf("%d", factor);
            num /= factor;
            ++power;
            if (power >= 1)
            {
                printf("^%d", power);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Choose a small number the decomposition of which is not too trivial, for example 12=2^2 x 3^2  and 60: 2^2 x 3 x 5 and try to follow your code with a paper sheet and a pencil. You should soon realize that it is wrong and why...

Comment: One issue I see right off: you never reset `power` to 0 at the beginning of each iteration of your `factor` loop.  For a simple program like this, you could easily try one of your simple failure cases and walk through the code by hand to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am a bit closer to a right answer, but still have some things to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four problems:

1. `power` is not being reset to 0 for each factor
2. It is printing `factor` even if `power` is 0.
3. It should not print the `factor` and `power` until `power` has been fully determined. (Currently, the code is printing every time `power` is incremented.
4. It prints `x` at the beginning if the first factor is > 2.

Fixed version below:

```
void prime_factors(int num)
{
    int power = 0;
    int first = 1;

    for (int factor = 2; num > 1; ++factor)
    {
        power = 0;
        while (num % factor == 0)
        {
            num /= factor;
            ++power;
        }
        if (power >= 1)
        {
            if (first)
                printf("%d", factor);
            else
                printf(" x %d", factor);
            printf("^%d", power);
            first = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

There are various ways to speed it up.

One way to speed it up is to skip factors when they get too large (larger than the square root of `num`, as suggested by **@chux** in the comments), leaving `num` as the only remaining factor. Rather than calculating the square root, a simple division can be used, as shown in the `// speed up 1` code section below:

```
void prime_factors(int num)
{
    int power = 0;
    int first = 1;

    for (int factor = 2; num > 1; ++factor)
    {
        power = 0;
        // speed up 1
        if (num / factor < factor)
        {
            // skip impossible factors
            factor = num;
        }
        // end of speed up 1
        while (num % factor == 0)
        {
            num /= factor;
            ++power;
        }
        if (power >= 1)
        {
            if (first)
                printf("%d", factor);
            else
                printf(" x %d", factor);
            printf("^%d", power);
            first = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to speed it up is to increment `factor` by 2 in the `for` loop most of the time, except when `factor` is 2, so the sequence will be 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, etc.:

```
    for (int factor = 2; num > 1; factor += 1 + (factor & 1))
```

The `factor += 1 + (factor & 1)` increments `factor` by 1 when `factor` is even, and increments `factor` by 2 when `factor` is odd, so the only even value of `factor` will be the initial value 2.

Comment: I added problem 4 and updated the code.

Comment: Aside: A definite speed improvement would limit iterations to the square root of `num`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was going to let OP consider speed-ups, but I added a couple of suggestions, including one based on your square root test.

Comment: Super, thank you